# I need clarification on ROOT password

Tags: password, root

Recently I was attempting a terminal command using `sudo`. I thought it wanted my administrative password, but it really wanted ROOT... Which I have forgotten or screwed up....so my objective failed.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Would you please tell me what I should do?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the command prior and post when it asked for your password? What command did you run? What were you expecting? What happened instead? Please read [ask] for more tips about writing questions.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu by default "root" account is disabled. You can login into root using following command in you terminal.

```
sudo su -
```

("-" switch in command makes it a login shell. That means your environment variables and everything is set up as root user. To run this command you should have `sudo` permission)

If you really want to enable root account you can use following command:

```
sudo passwd
```

Then you can login in as root like this:

```
su root
```

or just

```
su
```

But it is better to lock root account and user `sudo` command. You haven't forget it. There is no password for root by default.

Comment: I changed the answer little bit.